# How to get a log record before it is written to a file in runtime

Tags: java, logging, logback

We use our own wrapper over logback-classic 1.2.3 and, with certain settings, it becomes possible to change the pattern for writing a message to a file, in autotests I need to make sure that after changing the pattern, the logs are written in a new way. The idea of ​​reading a file doesn't fit. The idea is that through AOP to intercept the output, but I can not find the place where the appender writes to the file

I want to implement something like this:

```
public class ExampleTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTest.class);
    
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        String oldPattern = "%date %level [%thread] %logger{35} - %msg %n %xEx";
        String msg = "base pattern msg";
        LOGGER.warn(msg);
        String logRecord = getLoggedRecord(msg);
        // logRecord: 2022-08-02 17:25:24,984 WARN [main] logger.LoggerTest - old pattern msg
        compareRecordWithPattern(oldPattern, logRecord);
        String newPattern = "%date %level subsystem:%context{susystem} - %msg %n";
        changePattern(newPattern);
        msg = "new pattern msg";
        LOGGER.warn(msg);
        logRecord = getLoggedRecord(msg);
        //logRecord: 2022-08-02 17:25:24,984 WARN subsystem:MY_SUBSYSTEM - new pattern msg
        compareRecordWithPattern(newPattern, logRecord);
    }

    private String getLoggedRecord(String msg) {
        // here need to find the message that was written by the logger to the file
        return foundMessage;
    }

    private void changePattern(String newPattern) {
        ...
        // change pattern
        ...
    }

    private boolean compareRecordWithPattern(String pattern, String logRecord) {
        ...
        // compare
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the expected format and sample code, and configuration tried so far.

Comment: @user16320675 this is good advice, I'll try to implement it.

Comment: @AzharKhan updated. gave an example

Comment: The pattern of log msg can be configured in `logback.xml`. Is there any reason why you are not using it? https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Comment: @AzharKhan the pattern is just an example, i know it can be configured via logback.xml but i don't need it. My goal is to intercept the message that will be written to the log file(in runtime)

Comment: Go through logback official documentation, especially Layout and Encoder. https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html, https://logback.qos.ch/manual/encoders.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what i do:

```
@AfterReturning(
            pointcut = "execution(* ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder.encode(..))",
            returning = "bytes"
    )
public void hookEvent(byte[] bytes) {
        // add bytes converted to String to list
        }
```